# Internal server error 500 when upgrading to Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, upgrade, wampserver

I updated Laravel on the test server from Laravel 5 to 8. I have the following versions on my computer:

- php: 7.3.29
- wampserver: 3.2.5
- Laravel Framework: 8.42.0

When I want to access the software on the test server the following error occurs:

> internal server error 500

without any explanation.

Where does this come from, and how I can find more details about this error?

Comment: Take a look at the server logs to see more details. Did you follow Laravel's upgrade guides for each version?

Comment: As well as the server logs, have you also checked your Laravel logs in the `storage/logs` directory?

Comment: I have the following error message in the Apache error log file : "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace". Yes I followed the Laravel's upgrade guides for each versions.

Comment: This is an error from apache. Check, if your configuration, as well as your htaccess files, are up to date for Laravel 8. To circle the problem, do as the error message suggests and enable `LogLevel debug` in your apache conf.

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini and set the following values:

- `display_errors = 'On'`
- `error_reporting = E_ALL`

Reload your page. You should now be able to see, what caused the crash. PHP will throw an HTTP error 500, if you got a fatal error, when `display_errors` is set to `Off`, which is the default in the production php.ini.

Comment: Changes to php.ini require a server restart

Comment: Why not just use `ini_set('display_errors', '1');ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');error_reporting(E_ALL);` in a script?

Comment: You'd need to include it in all your scripts. If you're upgrading a whole project, it's easier to do a quick INI change, that applies globally. Afterwards, you change it back and don't have to backtrack, which files still have the debug info in.

Comment: @stui I already have 
`display_errors = 'On'
  error_reporting = E_ALL` in php.ini and still have the same issue

Comment: @stui No, you don't have to include it in all scripts, only in index.php. in that case you can do this without restarting services. The same info is found in the error log file too. Apart from that, this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @GertB. Yes, in a Laravel project. But I'm talking general PHP projects, that maybe don't have a central router.

Comment: WAMPServer some out of the box with error reporting turned on, so unless it is manually turned off ....